# SQUID Transparent Proxy: Error INVALID_URL and ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: proxy, squid, transparent-proxy

I configure squid proxy on Centos 7. I am using Squid version 3.5.20.
I also try squid 4.10 on Ubuntu 20.04, but I got the same problem. Maybe my ACL was wrong.

I configure DSTNAT on Router to intercept HTTP traffic from 192.168.1.0/24 to Squid Proxy 10.10.10.10:3128.

[image: topology]

This is /etc/squid/squid.conf file:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl whitelist_domain dstdomain “/etc/squid/whitelist.acl”

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow whitelist_domain
http_access deny all

http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%  0
refresh_pattern .               0   20%     4320
```

And this is the /etc/squid/whitelist.acl file:

```
linux.or.id
lipi.go.id
```

Please help me to find the problem.

So,regarding the above config, the client will be denied to access all http website, except linux.or.id and lipi.go.id. Right?

However, when I try to connect. All website has this error: INVALID URL
[image]

This is /var/log/squid/access.log

```
1633885185.900      0 192.168.1.251 TAG_NONE/400 3867 GET / - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1633885185.970      0 192.168.1.251 TCP_IMS_HIT/304 295 GET http://linux:3128/squid-internal-static/icons/SN.png - HIER_NONE/- image/png
```

I was trying to change the squid.conf like this:

```
http_access allow all
http_port 3128 intercept
http_port 3129
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%  0
refresh_pattern .               0   20%     4320
```

That ACL will allow all request.

However, I got ERROR ACCESS DENIED, which mean my ACL blocked the access right?

[image]